# Is it possible to add ondblclick to option field using new option()?

Tags: javascript, html-select

My code

```
var row2 =<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['row2']) ?>;
for (var i = 0; i < row2.length; i++) {
   if(row2[i][0] == x) {
      var select = document.getElementById("mTask");
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(row2[i][2], row2[i][1]);
   }
}
```

and it generates this in html

```
<select id="mTask" size="12">
  <option value="0">Rätt eller fel!</option>
  <option value="1">A Valles Verktygsaffär</option>
  <option value="2">A Stina för dagbok</option>
  <option value="3">A Dagbok för cykelverkstad</option>
  <option value="4">A Dagbok för elfirma</option>
  <option value="5">A Dagbok för innebandyklubb</option>
</select>
```

I would like the  looks like this, is it possible?

```
<option ondblclick="mainLink(270)">Rätt eller fel!</option>
```

Comment: I need to have the event ondblclick on it, have to find another solution for this!!!

Comment: and if i write this code direct into html it´s work fine!!!
<option ondblclick="mainLink(270)">Rätt eller fel!</option>

Comment: and thats my problem how to get the event from javascript new option()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `this` into the function which will reference the selected option. I only added it for the second choice.

Here is a better solution. Bind a single function to the select list and then use the data-attribute to store the 270 number.

http://jsfiddle.net/sUqVV/1/

```
<select id="mTask" size="12" ondblclick="mainLink2(this);">
    <option data-id="270" value="0">Rätt eller fel!</option>
    <option data-id="271" value="1">A Valles Verktygsaffär</option>
    <option data-id="272" value="2">A Stina för dagbok</option>
    <option data-id="273" value="3">A Dagbok för cykelverkstad</option>
    <option data-id="274" value="4">A Dagbok för elfirma</option>
    <option data-id="275" value="5">A Dagbok för innebandyklubb</option>
</select>
<script>
    function mainLink2(select) {
        var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        var dataAttrib = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
        alert( selectedValue + ':' + dataAttrib);
    }
</script>
​
```

OLD
http://jsfiddle.net/sUqVV/

```
<select id="mTask" size="12" ondblclick="mainLink2(this);">
    <option value="0">Rätt eller fel!</option>
    <option ondblclick="mainLink(270, this);" value="1">A Valles Verktygsaffär</option>
    <option value="2">A Stina för dagbok</option>
    <option value="3">A Dagbok för cykelverkstad</option>
    <option value="4">A Dagbok för elfirma</option>
    <option value="5">A Dagbok för innebandyklubb</option>
</select>
<script>
    function mainLink(id, option) {
        alert(id + ':' + option.value);
    }
</script>
```

​